# Access Count in combined query

Tags: function, count

My query is:

```
 SELECT Batch.printedquantity, Batch.guid
 FROM Batch
 WHERE (((Batch.[guid]) In (Select Main.guid
 from Main
 where (Left(main.printertimestamp,10) = [date]))));
```

so this returns like:

```
    printedquantity     guid
     3                  {5FCE6B9A-88B0-41F7-A52B-21E0375B0433}
     10                 {C73EB60D-D707-4717-B505-667C445CC294}
     1                  {FEC25696-6AD6-4218-B7EB-2E5593054DAB}
     1                  {6CCDFB48-6B1B-4712-8C08-F06DA220455C}
     1                  {6CCDFB48-6B1B-4712-8C08-F06DA220455C}
```

I am trying to get the total of the `printedquantity` column but having trouble with the 
count function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT() function returns the number of rows. To get the total of the printedquantity column it sounds like you're really after the SUM() function. Completely untested, but the following may help...

```
SELECT SUM(Batch.printedquantity)
 FROM Batch
 WHERE (((Batch.[guid]) In (Select Main.guid
 from Main
 where (Left(main.printertimestamp,10) = [date]))));
```